# Return data in TempData after OnPost in razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

i'm trying to return message after performing OnPost action in razor page using TempData, but nothing appear after post finish and the TempData is empty

please see below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostEdit(int id)
{     .....
      .....                 
      TempData["MSG"] = "done";
      return RedirectToPage("./Index");
 }
```

View:

```
@if (TempData["MSG"] != null)
{
   <div>
   @TempData["MSG"]
   </div>
 }
```

Any help ?

Comment: you are not returning view but calling another controller action method. In that case TempData will not be available. Try Session or Cookie variables

Comment: The code you shared should work fine as long as the view code you shared is for the `index` view.

Comment: @Shyju , thanks but it not working actually, when we redirect to the page, TempData become null

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code in to a local project and it worked as expected. Did you share the view code of `Index` ?

Comment: What version of Razor Pages are you using?

Comment: Asp.net core 2.1

Comment: @J.Edmond did you see this: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tempdata